# Bootstrap form size : impossible to reduce form

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

It's the first time I'm using `Bootstrap`. I need it to improve my `Django script` and more particularly `HTML templates`.

Boostrap form works pretty well but I would like to reduce Bootstrap form size.

My second version :

```
   <h1 align="center"> Formulaire d'acte de naissance </h1>

    {% load bootstrap %}
    <form class = "form-horizontal" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
        <h3> Formulaire permettant la création de l'acte de naissance</h3>
        {{ Bform|bootstrap}} </td><!-- Display child part formulary -->
        {{ value|date:"%d/%m/%Y" }}
        {{ value|time:"H:M" }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    <br></br>

    <input class="button" type ="submit" name="_save2" value="Valider l'acte de naissance" /> 
    <input class="button" type ="submit" name="_preview2" value="Prévisualiser l'acte de naissance" />
    <form method='POST' action="{% url "home" %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="button" type ="submit" name="retour" value="Retour" /> 
    </form>
    </form>
```

Bootstrap form display :

[image]

How I can reduce size with maybe css file ?

Thank you !

Comment: There is no `action`. It is empty. Maybe the issue? ... and nested `<form>` is not valid HTML!

Comment: What do you mean by, `don't seem to work`?

Comment: Before to add bootstrap elements, I could validate or preview my form (`Bform)`. I added bootstrap in order to 'decorate' my django project. When I fill the form, I can validate it or preview it. Maybe I miss something but buttons don't make something from now.